# Broken anchor element in employer search results preview of Personal Statement

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I just noticed that depending on where a link falls in the Personal Statement preview text in the Private View, it can cause a truncation.

For example, entering the following dummy text in the Personal Statement box in the Edit CV form:

```
Suspendisse tellus felis, fringilla at ad [sd-des](http://www.example.com). ut auctor eleifend, elit tellus malesuada magna, nec pharetra dui neque quis [euismod](http://www.example.com) in sed ligula.
```

Ends up looking like this in the source code:

```
<div class="summary"><p>Suspendisse tellus felis, fringilla at ad <a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">sd-des</a>. ut auctor eleifend, elit tellus malesuada magna, nec pharetra dui neque quis <a href="http://w&hellip;</div>
```

Where the ellipsis code crashes into the anchor code and results in the text not displaying on the page correctly. Not sure if links are allowed there, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: FWIW, this effect also occurs on the employer search result page.  Brent Ozar's entry was the one where I noticed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complicated -- but I'll just call the [SanitizeHtml()](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html) function again to strip any HTML that is broken by the summary truncation.

Won't be deployed until Monday, FYI.